# How to access values from a custom value.yaml files in templates (HELM)

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to access the key - values from a custom value file `secretvalues.yaml` passed to helm with the `-f` parameter. The key - value in this file is being passed to the yaml file `postgres.configmap.yml`.

here is my folder structure (there are there are a few other charts but I have removed them for simplicity)

```
├── k8shelmcharts
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── charts
│   │   ├── postgres-service
│   │   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   │   ├── postgres.configmap.yml
│   │   │   │   ├── postgres.deployment.yml
│   │   │   │   └── postgres.service.yml
│   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   └── secretvalues.yaml
```

The contents of the `values.yaml` file in the `postgres-services/` folder is

```
config:
  postgres_admin_name: "postgres"
```

The contents of the `secretvalues.yaml` file in the `k8shelmchars/` folder is

```
secrets:
  postgres_admin_password: "password"
```

and the contents of the `postgres.configmap.yml` file in the `postgres-services/` folder is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  POSTGRES_USER: {{ .Values.config.postgres_admin_name }}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: {{ .secretvalues.secrets.postgres_admin_password }}
```

I have tried several combinations here like `.secretvalues.secrets.postgres_admin_password`, `.Secretvalues.secrets.postgres_admin_password` and tried to remove the `secrets` key but no avail.

When I run the command to install the charts `helm install -f k8shelmcharts/secretvalues.yaml testapp k8shelmcharts/ --dry-run --debug`
I get the error:

```
Error: template: flask-k8s-app/charts/postgresdb/templates/postgres.configmap.yml:8:37: executing "flask-k8s-app/charts/postgresdb/templates/postgres.configmap.yml" at <.secretvalues.parameters.postgres_admin_password>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.parameters
helm.go:94: [debug] template: flask-k8s-app/charts/postgresdb/templates/postgres.configmap.yml:8:37: executing "flask-k8s-app/charts/postgresdb/templates/postgres.configmap.yml" at <.secretvalues.parameters.postgres_admin_password>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.parameters
```

my question is how do I access the `secret.postgres_admin_password` ?

I am using `helm3`

Thanks!

---

Trying to access the key-values from the `secretvalues.yaml` file by using `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: {{ .Values.config.postgres_admin_password }}` in the `postgres.configmap.yml` seems to pull null/nil values.

I am getting the error when I run `helm install testapp k8shelmcharts/ --dry-run --debug -f k8shelmcharts/secretvalues.yaml`:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: unknown object type "nil" in ConfigMap.data.POSTGRES_PASSWORD
helm.go:94: [debug] error validating "": error validating data: unknown object type "nil" in ConfigMap.data.POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

When I try to debug the template using `helm template k8shelmcharts/ --debug`, I see:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
```

indicating helm is not able to pull values from the `secretvalues.yaml` file. NOTE: I have updated the key from `secrets` to `config` in the  `secretvalues.yaml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values from all files are merged into one object `Values`, so you should access variables from the `secretvalues.yaml` the same way you access the others, i.e.

```
.Values.secrets.postgres_admin_password
```

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor not entirely, it's throwing a different error now. I have updated the question with my observations.