# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL in Helm as Dependency in Minikube

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, minikube

## Working Setup

I can run the following without any issues:

1. Install PostgreSQL using: `helm install postgresql bitnami/postgresql`
2. Get the appropriate password: `export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode)`
3. Connect using the test command: `kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.13.0-debian-10-r25 --env="PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" --command -- psql --host postgresql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432`
4. List all tables at the prompt using `\l`
5. Exit and remove the deployment: `helm delete postgresql`

## What Is Not Working

I created a new Helm chart of my own and have this in my **Chart.yaml** file with a completely blank **values.yaml** file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: test
description: testing
type: application
version: 0.0.1
appVersion: 0.0.1

dependencies:
- name: postgresql
  version: 10.9.5
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

Helm install works fine using: `helm install test .`

Once that is set up I can get the password almost the same way:

```sh
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret test-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode)
echo ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

When I run the launch command I get an error:

```sh
kubectl run test-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' \
      --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.13.0-debian-10-r25 \
      --env="PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" \
      --command \
      -- psql --host test-postgresql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
```

The error is:

> sql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
> pod "test-postgresql-client" deleted
> pod default/test-postgresql-client terminated (Error)

I updated my **values.yaml** to include:

```yaml
global:
  # Dependency: PostgreSQL
  postgresql:
    postgresqlDatabase: my-test
    postgresqlUsername: my-test
    postgresqlPassword: my-test
```

If I go into the pod that launches and check the secrets, I see it picks up the values properly, but I get a similar error when I try to connect using those credentials.

What am I missing in the chart setup to deploy this as a dependency and be able to connect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access values from a custom value.yaml files in templates (HELM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128483/how-to-access-values-from-a-custom-value-yaml-files-in-templates-helm)

Comment: @AlexG the problem isn't value access - it's connectivity

Comment: I ran this instead thinking maybe the bitnami image is messed up somehow: `kubectl run --rm -it postgres-client --image=postgres:9.6.23-stretch --restart=Never -- psql -U postgres -h test-postgresql -W` ... that seems to have worked. I think I'll open a bug with bitnami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent hours trying to debug the issue.
If you are running the helm chart for the `second` time, make sure you have deleted any existing PV, PVCs from previous installations.

> WARNING: The configured password will be ignored on new installation in case when previous Posgresql release was deleted through the helm command. In that case, old PVC will have an old password, and setting it through helm won't take effect. Deleting persistent volumes (PVs) will solve the issue.

> Delete the PV and PVC if you are getting the error: "psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username"

I guess, this should be highlighted more clearly in the documentation

You can try the following to test

```bash
$ export POSTGRES_USER_PASSWORD='<admin_user>'   # Admin user : postgres
$ export KEYCLOAK_USER_PASSWORD='<keycloak_user>'    # Custom user : keycloak

$ helm install keycloak-db postgresql \
--namespace keycloak \
--create-namespace \
--set global.postgresql.auth.postgresPassword="$POSTGRES_USER_PASSWORD" \
--set global.postgresql.auth.username="keycloak" \
--set global.postgresql.auth.password="$KEYCLOAK_USER_PASSWORD" \
--set global.postgresql.auth.database="keycloak_db" 


$ export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace keycloak keycloak-db-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d)

$ kubectl run keycloak-db-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace keycloak --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:15.3.0-debian-11-r17 --env="PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" \
      --command -- psql --host keycloak-db-postgresql -U keycloak -d keycloak_db -p 5432
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

keycloak_db=>
```